# Was the Cold Steel Reign GM's guide ever published?

Tags: campaign-settings, cold-steel-reign

Does anyone know if Mad Hermit Games ever published the Cold Steel Reign GM's guide?  If not, does anyone know of any source books/material that they published?  I liked the world background, just was disappointed that the player guide is just a large set of rules...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like the answer is no.

Back in June, they were working on making the GM's guide available online, but since then their website has disappeared, and they haven't updated their Facebook status in all that time.  See for yourself at their [Facebook page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Cold-Steel-Reign/254268613577).

There's a GM screen for Cold Steel Reign available at [Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Cold-Steel-Reign-GM-Screen/dp/1889016020), so at least something GM-oriented is available, not that it's much consolation.

I'm not optimistic that we'll see a GM's guide for this game any time soon.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question but thought I'd post an answer anyway...

Mad Hermit Games did actually release a GM's guide and a sourcebook, called the Dakota Territories, for CSR as PDF's which you bought and downloaded via their website. I can't remember exactly when I bought them, I think it was towards the begininng of last year but I can't be sure.

The GM's guide, at the time that I purchased it, was split into 10 pdf files (one file for each chapter) and is around 450-500 pages in length.

The sourcebook is a 41 page pdf detailing the Dakota Territories - includes geography of the region, the Barons of the region, encounter tables, usual sort of sourcebook stuff really.

I just thought I'd let people know that there is material out there, just might be tricky finding it!

Comment: Thanks, that is really helpful indeed.  Do you have any links to official sources of the PDFs? *By official, I mean where you can purchase/download it legally, no warez site advertising is allowed here.*

Comment: I don't unfortunately, the only links I had were on their website.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is sadly, "No, I don't think the GM Guide for CSR will ever be released to the public nor will any other source material aside from the Player's Guide and the GM Screen which were released years ago."  For detailed evidence supporting this conclusion please read on.

Long long ago at Origins in Columbus Ohio I played CSR with its creator, Patrick Ellison, and was so impressed by the concept that I immediately bought the Player's Guide and pre-ordered for a serious chunk of change the "soon to be released" Gamemaster's Guide.  Once I arrived home I immediately became active on their website forum and joined with the many who had given their money in excitedly taking part in any discussion on the game and its development.  Months passed and the updates from Patrick Ellison assuring us that though significantly delayed the guide would be forthcoming became more and more seldom.  Finally after months of no message at all from Patrick the site disappeared along with all of our money.

I personally emailed Ellison several times saying that I would be fine with him keeping my money if he would send me a PDF of whatever work he has completed on the GM Guide.  No response.  CSR has since been my bitterest disappointment and resentment in gaming.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! I see you are seemingly new to Stackexchange. In that case have a look at our [FAQ]. I don't personally see this as much of an answer to this question. There is a lot of context and not much content. If you'd like to edit this into more of an answer feel free to ping me to remove the down vote.

Comment: I think this answer could be edited some but I think it's on topic for the question - it says no, with details.  Dissent, you might consider ramping back the off topic part.

Answer (score 5):

I also purchased the GM guide through the website although unfortunately it seems as though Patrick has taken it down again.  If you're interested try posting on any of [the](https://www.facebook.com/pages/cold-steel-reign/47998869289) [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Mad-Hermit-Games/253942583814) [pages](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Cold-Steel-Reign/254268613577) in an effort to stir Patrick into bringing things online again. I know he was also working on the Bestiary and an additional Character Cats book. I don't know if he's finished these yet.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but I never stumbled on this site until just now. There is a pdf of the DM Guide and also the Dakota Territories supplement. These will not be released in a print version. However, you can post a request for them on the official [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/coldsteelreign/). If you send a request with your email address and which, or both, books you would like, I can send you a download link for free.

Comment: Are you associated with Mad Hermit Games and/or Cold Steel Reign? If so, you should include that in your answer—both because it will make your answer more authoritative, and because we generally prefer answers to disclose relationships with products under discussion.

Comment: First, I am not infected with facebook so that is of limited use. Second, unless you are officially affiliated, then a "free" copy would breach stack rules.